# convert number to proper format

Tags: string, xslt, xpath, numbers

I'm getting output from generated code as the following in a format of res 2^-2.:

```
/*!< @VAR_NAME VehSpd @RES 2^-2 @MIN 0 @MAX 182.5 */
```

I would like to get 0.250 instead of 2^-2 to be:

```
/*!< @VAR_NAME VehSpd @RES 0.250 @MIN 0 @MAX 182.5 */
```

in XSL they put the format of the line as :

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat( $newline, ' /*!&lt;',
' @VAR_NAME ', $curr_node/@name,@struct-component-name,
' @RES ',  @res,
' @MIN ',  @min-val,
' @MAX ',  @max-val)"/>
```

is there away to convert format 2^-2 to show as 0.250.
I tried number(@res), but it gives me NaN.
any idea?
by the way, I'm not sure if @res is a number or a string

Comment: in XSL the format is as the following:  <xsl:value-of select="concat( $newline, ' /*!&lt;',
 ' atVAR_NAME ', $curr_node/atname,atstruct-component-name,
 ' atRES ',  atres,
 ' atMIN ',  atmin-val,
 ' atMAX ',  atmax-val)"/>

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? There might be an easy way to do this using an extension function.

Answer (score 0):

The value `2^-2` is a string value of a mathematic expression, not a number. You need to do the math to produce the correct number.

If you could use XSLT/XPath 3.0, there is a convenient [math:pow()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-math-pow) function available. You could simply use:

```
math:pow(number(substring-before(@min-val, "^")), number(substring-after(@min-val, "^")))
```

Otherwise, you need to find a way to parse it and do the work. [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev)'s [FXSL](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/) library has templates available that might be helpful. The site provides an [example](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/xslCalculator/The%20FXSL%20Calculator.html) using the pow template. Something like this:

```
<xsl:import href="exp.xsl"/>
<xsl:call-template name="pow">
  <xsl:with-param name="pBase" select="2"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="pPower" select="-2"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```